# flutter firebase is there any query to make OR query on fields?

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, where-clause

This is my stream:

```
stream: chatRef
          .where('id', isEqualTo: this.currentUserId)
          .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
```

I want to make a query where 'id is equal to this.currentUserId OR 'otherId' is equal to this.currentUserId but i cant find a simple way to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.where('id', whereIn: [this.currentUserId, otherId])
```